# Region of Interest selection error in Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (Error: unable to calculate)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, landsat, image-classification, scp

[image: Semi Automatic Classification Plugin error]

Yesterday I upgraded the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. Immediately after doing this, the automatic ROI selection is giving me that error as shown in the attached image. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the plugin, but nothing is changing. How can I fix this?